# Probabilities of Circuit breakers being closed

Tags: probability

The circuit breakers in the following two figures
are closed independently with the following probabilities.
[image: Circuit]

- P(1st breaker is closed) = 0.3
- P(2nd breaker is closed) = 0.4
- P(3rd breaker is closed) = 0.5
- P(4th breaker is closed) = 0.6
- P(5th breaker is closed) = 0.7

What is the probability that current can flow from A to B? Hint: Consider separately the cases that 3 is open and closed.

Here is what I have worked out:
**Case one - Switch 3 is open:**
Assume switch $i$ is closed with probability $p_i.$ Let $S_i$ be the event that $i$ is closed, $C_1$ the event that current can flow through the top branch, $C_2$ the event that the current can flow through the bottom branch, and $D_1$ the event that current flows from $A$ to $B$
Then, $$C_1=S_1S_4, C_2=S_2S_5$$ $$D_1=C_1\cup C_2$$
Now we find the probability $$\begin{align}P(D_1)&=P(C_1\cup C_2)\\ &= P(C_1)+P(C_2)-P(C_1\cap C_2)\\ &= P(S_1S_4)+P(S_2S_5)-P(S_1S_4S_2S_5)\\ &= p_1p_4+p_2p_5-p_1p_4p_2p_5\\ &=(0.3)(0.6)+(0.4)(0.7)-(0.3)(0.6)(0.4)(0.7)\\ &= 0.4096\end{align}$$

**Case two - Switch 3 is closed:** Let us assume the same events as the previous case, but add one more. Let $C_3$ be the case that switch three is closed.
Now, $$C_3=S_3$$ And $$D_2=(C_1\cup C_2) \cap C_3$$
The probability is $$\begin{align} P(D_2) &= P((C_1\cup C_2) \cap C_3)\\ &= P((C_1\cap C_3) \cup (C_2\cap C_3))\\ &=P(C_1\cap C_3)+P(C_2\cap C_3)-P(C_1\cap C_3 \cap C_2 \cap C_3)\\ &= P(S_1S_4S_3)+P(S_2S_5S_3)-P(S_1S_4S_3S_2S_5S_3)\\ &=p_1p_4p_3+p_2p_5p_3-p_1p_4p_3p_2p_5p_3\\ &=(0.3)(0.6)(0.5)+(0.4)(0.7)(0.5)-(0.3)(0.6)(0.5)(0.4)(0.7)(0.5)\\ &=0.2174\end{align}$$

The probabilites of both of these events are $P(D_1)+P(D_2)=0.627$. Is this correct?

Comment: It seems that the question is asking specifically what the probability is that there is only one path that the current will flow. Otherwise, one can enumerate the paths, and calculate a simple sum of products.

Comment: I only did this because of the hint, which says to consider path 3 being close separately. I took that to mean I can assume one case with 3 open and one where it is close.

Answer (score 1):

When switch $3$ is closed it effectively shrinks to a point, and then current flows iff ($1$ or $2$ is closed) AND ($4$ or $5$ is closed):
$$P(D_2)=(0.3+0.4-0.12)(0.6+0.7-0.42)=0.5104$$
Your $P(D_1)$ is correct, but since $P(S_3)=0.5$ the $P(D_i)$ need to be blended together using it rather than simply added:
$$P=0.5(0.4096+0.5104)=0.46$$